# Does Medical Breakthrough still have its effect when forfeited for rezzing Archer?

Tags: android-netrunner

To rez [Archer](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=archer), I need to forfeit an agenda.

[Medical Breakthrough](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05005) has the ability of reducing each subsequent Medical Breakthrough's advancement requirement by 1; whether it's in the runners or corps score area.

Therefore, essentially, I wanted to confirm whether forfeited cards leave the score area, and hence in this case, not have an effect on future cards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing about Medical Breakthrough that would function differently than other agendas upon forfeit.  Forfeited agendas no longer affect the game either for points or for their abilities.

---

### Details

Medical Breakthrough's ability is:

> Lower the advancement requirement of each Medical Breakthrough by 1.
> This ability is active even while Medical Breakthrough is in the
> Runner's score area.

It's not that the installed copy of Medical Breakthrough looks to see how many Medical Breakthroughs are in the score area.  Each Medical Breakthrough in the score area has an ability that modifies the advancement requirement of the installed copy.  However, this doesn't matter, because Medical Breakthrough leaves the score area when it is forfeited.

Additionally, from the core rules, page 22:

> **Forfeiting Agendas**
>
> Some card abilities require the Corporation or Runner to forfeit an agenda. When a player forfeits an agenda, he
> selects any agenda in his score area and permanently removes it from
> the game (it does not go to Archives or the heap). He no longer scores
> points for the forfeited agenda.

Given the Medical Breakthrough is removed from the game, it is in neither player's score area and its ability is no longer active:

> While an agenda is in the Corporation’s score area, it is active and
> adds its agenda points to his score.
>
> ---
>
> Constant Abilities
>
> Constant abilities continually affect the game as long as **the card
> they appear on is active** and any other specified conditions are met.